# Is the `windows-8.1-preview` tag really needed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup-request

As the title says, is the [windows-8.1-preview](https://superuser.com/tags/windows-8.1-preview/info) tag *really* needed, especially as we're near the release of the Windows 9 Developer Preview (or beta, whatever it is).

The Windows 8.1 Preview is over a year old, and is no longer available for download from Microsoft.
Any sane developer would use a full Windows 8.1 installation, which is up-to-date, and not the Windows 8.1 Preview which is no longer updated or maintained.

Shouldn't this tag be purged, or at least merged into the [windows-8.1](https://superuser.com/tags/windows-8.1/info) tag?
If not, why?

Comment: questions in the tag needs to be cleaned up/removed/updated

Comment: Keep in mind that those questions could be specific to that version of Windows and might not relate to the final version of Windows.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Then surely those questions should be purged completely from Super User; they're not going to hep any future visitors with fixing any issues.

Comment: @zyboxenterprises I agree. I just wanted to leave a quick comment :-) Although I would prefer closure to deletion

Comment: Instead of a purge why not protect them? I do agree they have limited usefulness though.

Comment: We could historic-lock the better questions (ones about updating to a release version or workarounds for known bugs etc), retag those which apply equally to [windows-8.1], and VTC those which no longer apply. Other than that, we will need to be vigilant in retagging new questions.

Comment: I agree with the closing or locking; deleting may remove reputation people have rightfully earned.

Comment: note that posts with [score +3 & on site for  > 60 days don't lose rep](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) when deleted